# 2 variables calculus word problem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

A certain factory using $x$ do-dads and $y$ widgets per hour will produce:

$T(x,y)=\frac{90x^2}{y}$

thingamabobs per day.

Describe the relationship between inputs  $x$ and $y$ such that $3600$ thingamabobs are produced per day. (That is, find the level curve of $T$ corresponding to $T = 3600.$)

My answer is wrong and I'm not sure why. This is what I did.

$$3600=90x^2y$$

$$\frac{3600}{90x^2}=y$$

$$\frac{40}{x^2}= y$$

Where did I go wrong in answering this question? What should the right solution be?

Comment: Look carefully through what you have written. Check your own step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in the very first line.  We have

$$
T(x, y) = \frac{90x^2}{y}
$$

and we want to set $T(x, y) = 3600$, but you wrote

$$
3600 = 90x^2y
$$

---

If we instead begin

$$
3600 = \frac{90x^2}{y}
$$

then we can multiply both sides by $\frac{y}{3600}$ to get

$$
y = \frac{x^2}{40}
$$

which is the reciprocal of your expression.  This kind of makes sense because your original set-up had $y$ where you should have had $\frac{1}{y}$.

There are, of course, other ways to express this basic relationship, all fundamentally equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

In the first equation you wrote $y$ jumped up into the numerator.